# Is it better style to check presence of a variable in an if statement or use a guard statement?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

Which of the following would you consider better style and why? Examples written in Ruby.

```
if number && number < 10
  ...
else
  nil
end
```

or

```
return nil if number.blank?

if number < 10
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a guard clause because it reduces the nesting level. However, your second code is only half-way guard clause, and it also has redundant `nil` value, and is not equivalent to the first code. Improving it would be:

```
return unless number && number < 10
...
```

Some people may not like it, but (provided that `number` is never `false`) I would write:

```
return unless number&.<(10)
...
```